# Drupal 7 Form API Theming #autocomplete textbox with long text

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-fapi

I have a textbox on a form that uses the #autocomplete property to provide a drop down list of options based on the text the user enters. This works great, except that some of the descriptions are very long, and don't fit in the width of the drop down.

Is it possible to make the drop down list options wrap onto more than one line so the full description is visible?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get text to wrap in a drop down without a js plugin.

Something [like this](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu) may be suitable.

Alternativly there is a Drupal module: [jQuery selectBox](https://drupal.org/project/selectbox)

Comment: That looks very useful. Any tips on how hard it would be to integrate with a Drupal page?

Comment: Should not be too hard - just include the js and necessary html. Alternatively I've added a link to a Drupal module that provides the same functionality.